# How can I use row values to index into another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have Google Sheets `Data`.

```
alpha    | 0.1
beta     | 0.2
gamma    | 0.3
delta    | 0.4
epsilon  | 0.5
```

and another sheet in the same file, `Data Subset`, that holds **an arbitrary number** of *row indices* to the first sheet.  E.g.:

```
2
4
5
```

What formula could I put in `Data Subset` that would allow me to pull data from the rows indicated by the first column?

e.g.:

```
2 | beta     | 0.2
4 | delta    | 0.4
5 | epsilon  | 0.5
```

Comment: I wasn't successful in creating a formula that uses `ARRAYFORMULA` or `VLOOKUP`. I hope that particular solution will come eventually.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I hope so too.  Your formula examples work, but only when exactly 3 rows index exactly 2 columns.  I will post a scalable solution if I find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found three solutions for you.

### Formula

`=INDIRECT("DATA!A"&A1)`
[image]

### Google Apps Script

```
function dataSubset(data,subset) {
  var output = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=subset.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    for(var j=1, jLen=data.length+1; j<jLen; j++) {
      if(parseInt(subset[i]) == parseInt(j)) {
        output.push(data[j-1]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

[image]

### Formula only available in the new Google Spreadsheet

`=ARRAY_ROW(INDIRECT("DATA!A"&A1),INDIRECT("DATA!B"&A1))`

### Example

I've prepared two example files for you:

1. [Old](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdE16UkNMX3I4M3R0TWlncDc1OW5aLUE&usp=sharing)
2. [New](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sr4GI6lxMCk8SgM4DoXujt4eJutYAvI--JLqZcQMGP8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the index function.

In B1 enter:

```
=INDEX(Data!A$1:A$5,$A1)
```

then you can copy and paste this to the rest of the cells in columns B and C